$\|A\|\le\rho(A)+\varepsilon$ as well as $\|B\|\le\rho(B)+\varepsilon$ for the same norm and $\varepsilon$
A well known lemma about the spectral radius of a matrix and the induced matrix norm is that $\forall \varepsilon>0$, there exists an induced matrix norm $\|\cdot\|=\|\cdot\|_{A, \,\varepsilon}$ such that $\|A\|\le\rho(A)+\varepsilon$.
Now the question is that, given two matrices, can we find a shared norm such that $$\|A\|\le\rho(A)+\varepsilon \quad\text{as well as}\quad \|B\|\le\rho(B)+\varepsilon$$

No. If for every pair of matrices $A,B$ and pre-specified $\epsilon$ we can find such a norm, we will have
$$
\rho(A+B)\le\|A+B\|\le\|A\|+\|B\|\le\rho(A)+\rho(B)+2\epsilon.
$$
Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, we must have $\rho(A+B)\le\rho(A)+\rho(B)$. However, this inequality does not always hold. Consider $A=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&0}$ and $B=A^T$ for instance.
